# Yii2 why the PhpStorm doesn't autocomplete Unit tests methods

Tags: yii2

My test looks like:

```
<?php

namespace backend\tests\unit;

use backend\modules\crm\models\CrmClient;

class ClientTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    /**
     * @var \frontend\tests\UnitTester
     */
    protected $tester;

    public function testClientFields()
    {
        $client = new CrmClient();

        $client->setCompany('12345');
        $this->assertTrue($client->validate(['company']));
    }
}
```

But by typing `$this->` doesn't show list of methods like `assertTrue, assertFalse` e.g. Is it normal and can I make it show them ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call codeception build command, eg. `./vendor/bin/codecept build` to generate base classes for all suites. This generate helper functions with documentation in folder `/tests/_support/_generated/` (basic tests folder structure).

Second solution:
Pass `UnitTester` variable into function and then use it instead of `$this`, eg:

```
public function testClientFields(UnitTester $I)
{
    $client = new CrmClient();

    $client->setCompany('12345');
    $I->assertTrue($client->validate(['company']));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank youu!

Comment: Just one more thing. Both solutions works but on the second I get : 
`[ArgumentCountError] Too few arguments to function backend\tests\unit\ClientTest::testClientFields(), 0 passed in /home/projects/toma/transport/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1153 and exactly 1 expected` because of the argument. Where should I set it ?

Comment: Try to remove `extends \Codeception\Test\Unit` and `$tester` variable, is not needed anymore.